# How to move settings to a new ADSL router?

Tags: router, connection

I have Virgin Media ADSL service (eww) and the awful D-Link DSL-2640R router that came with it.  I recently swapped it out for a Netgear DGN2200 router.  I duplicated all the old settings perfectly on the new one.

Now, the modem status just swaps between: `Training`, `Negotiating` and `Disconnected`.

Apart from bodged firmware or incorrect login settings, what could be the problem?

Comment: Anytime you swap out a modem, if it is not a bridged connection then you need to ensure that you have the correct PVC details for the circuit. This obviously wasn't the issue here, but it is a potential problem that may help others who come across this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect connection settings.

Some ISPs work only with very strict non-default settings that you cannot set on all modem/routers, so your new one may or may not work with your ISP.

Check the exact connection settings on your old router, not only username and password, and see if you can duplicate all of these on your new modem/router.

Answer (score 0):

Would add to @rems that some ISPs associate the MAC address of their modem to their server.  New MAC address means no IP so no connection.

Answer (score 0):

okay just to close this case. was on the phone for several hours sorting with both Virgin and Netgear lol. eventually they said okay we can see you trying to connect but its not getting all the way through. so they reset my username/pass (same details as i ws entering n was given), then suddently it just started to work...i blame them lol as i didnt change anything my end lol